# using iFrame to show external website but it is Just Blank

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I am facing an issue with a simple iFrame in visualForce page. I am getting Just a blank page even with '/home/home.jsp' which is salesforce HOme page. Whatever you give to `src="https://someaddress.com"`, it's just blank. I have checked Session settings and in different browsers and all. 
I am not getting a clue why a simple iFrame is not showing in VisualForce page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" Extensions="Quotejson2" action="{!eSign_iFrame}">
   <apex:form id="iFramePage">
   <center>
       <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!back}"/>
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:iframe rendered="iFramePage" frameborder="true" width="1000px" height="800px" src="{!eSignUrl}" scrolling="true"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!back}"/>
   </center>
```

eSignUrl string has the URL stored and returned from eSign_iFrame method in Quotejson2 class.
Please let me know if there is anything can be done to get it worked. 
Thank you,
Ashok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the console in your browser to look for error messages.

It's most likely that you'll see one of two things in the console:

1. `Mixed Content: The page at 'salesforce-address' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'address'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` If you get this, make sure that you use https in the src for your iframe. This may solve your problem.
2. `Refused to display 'address' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` This means the external site is set up so that it cannot be displayed in an iframe, so you're stuck unless you have some way of whitelisting Salesforce with the other site.

Number 2 is a standard thing these days. It prevents you from setting up some evil site with an iframe containing a trusted site so that you can attempt to fool people into giving your sensitive information.

Comment: 2nd point that you mentioned is correct. It is a X-FRAME options. 
'Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.com/signTST_backend/login does not permit framing.' This is the error that I got under CONSOLE. It's now fixed. Thank you.